# How do I stop the response message of a PHP script appearing as the only content of the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I have a simple Registration page, and the Javascript request works okay, but when the response is sent back in changes the page location to

/RegisterNewUser.php?Name=Andrew&Surname=Too&userID=0014&passWD=pass

and there is nothing displayed on the page but the response. I have tried changing page location manually but that doesn't seem to work

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Email Client</h1>
            <a href="login.html">
            <div class="topButton">Log in</div>
            </a>
        <h3>New User Registration</h3>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        <form name="register" action="RegisterNewUser.php" method"get";>
            First Name:<input type="text" name="Name"/><br/>
            Surname:<input type="text" name="Surname"/><br/>
            User ID:<input type="text" name="userID" id="userID"/><br/>         
            Password:<input type="password" name="passWD" id="pass1"/><br/>
            Re-enter password:<input type="password" id="pass2"/><br/>
            <div id="feedback"></div>
            <!--Inline validation of whether the passwords match-->
            <input type="submit" value="Register" id="regSubmit">
            <div id="formFeedback"></div>
            <!--If "user ID exists" is retuned, make it an alert, e.g. alert("That user ID is         taken, please try another.")-->
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
var xhr=null;
function registrationCheck(){
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
       xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
       xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    else {alert("Your browser does not support Ajax");}
    if (xhr!=null){  
         xhr.onreadystatechange=Response;
         xhr.open('POST','RegisterNewUser.php',false);
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
             xhr.send("Name=personName&Surname=personSurname&userID=personID&passWD=personpassword");
     }
}
function Response()
{
    if (xhr.readyState==4)
        {
            if (xhr.status==200)
                {
                var response=xhr.responseText;
                if(response == 'registered')
                    {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        alert('User already Exists');
                    }                   
                }
            else
                {
                    alert('Error!');
                }
        }
}   
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#regSubmit').on('change', function(){
            registrationCheck();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There is a `;` in `method"get";>` and missing `=` sign. Do `method="get">`

Comment: You aren't stopping the form from being submitted, so the browser is doing what it's supposed to: submitting the form and taking you to the form's `action`. Since it's via GET, the form fields will be added to the url as part of the query string.

Comment: You should catch the form submit event instead of the change of the button value and prevent the default action for that event in your javascript event handler function.

Comment: `method"get";>` <= doesn't help @jeroen ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- `GET` is the default so I guess the browser just ignores that part and submits the form anyway. The OP's results confirm that. It certainly doesn't help though :-)

Comment: @jeroen *ah* Ok, that makes sense. Still bad form though.

Comment: So how I do make it go to a different page for example inbox.html instead of the php url? the get form was a typo, my mistake. it doesn't affect the request as it works its just the changing of the page im confused about

Comment: I noticed you're passing a password in the URL; I strongly suggest against it. You're way better off using a POST method and using a proper password hashing method. What looks to me that you're storing passwords in plain text. In doing so, will be a question of time before your site gets compromised. ***Re-think this.***

Comment: Will do thanks, the html was written by a class mate I will be changing bits

Comment: You're welcome Andrew. I don't like hackers; nobody should. It's just a waste of time, energy and karma that could be spent better elsewhere. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should add "click" event not "change" event
and add "return false;" at end of your statement

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#regSubmit').on('click', function(event){
        registrationCheck();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Doing this returns user exists for users that aren't registered –

Comment: in this case you have a problem in your php file "RegisterNewUser.php" not in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent the default submit behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#regSubmit').on('change', function(event){
        registrationCheck();

        event.preventDefault();
        event.unbind();
    });
});
```